# Extracting date from hex dump (created in GFA Basic)

Tags: date, basic, hexdump

Thanks for looking at my problem.
Really bashing my head against the wall.

I'm trying to extract the date from a bunch of .bin files. The files are (probably) created by a program written in GFA Basic. I have a sample of labelled sequences.

I think I've narrowed down the header to this sequence, within which I think that the date-time stamp must be (I don't have labelled times to hand, but I only need to be able to extract the date).

Can anyone help me figure out the date from these hex sequences? I can't seem to decipher the pattern here.

Update: if this is indeed an object written in GFA Basic, I found the following info out:
(Source: http://freddo.chez.com/GfaBasic/GFABASIC.TXT )

~XBIOS(22,L:t%)

```
       Sets date and time

       t%       Bits 0-4:   seconds
                     5-19:  minutes           
                     11-15: hours
                     16-20: day
                     21-24: month
                     25-31: year - 1980
```

Any pointers would be amazing.
Thanks again.

```
06/03/2017   70 00 F3 02 31 FF 00 00 BC 15 12 04 3C 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 0C 00 FB FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2017   70 00 F3 02 31 FF 00 00 BA 15 12 04 3C 00 00 00 00 00 FC FF FA FF FC FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2019   76 01 EF 02 FE FF 00 00 7F 52 11 04 8A 28 00 00 00 00 0D 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2019   76 01 EF 02 FE FF 00 00 81 52 12 04 73 30 00 00 00 00 F9 FF E9 FF F1 D8 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2019   76 01 EF 02 FE FF 00 00 7D 52 0D 04 58 00 00 00 00 00 F4 FF 05 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2019   76 01 EF 02 FE FF 00 00 83 52 12 04 A0 33 00 00 00 00 F9 FF 0D 00 F2 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 78 66 0C 04 28 08 00 00 00 00 09 00 05 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 81 66 0F 04 98 20 00 00 00 00 19 00 0D 00 FA FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 80 66 0E 04 BA 1E 00 00 00 00 05 00 14 00 FC FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 7A 66 0C 04 DA 09 00 00 00 00 0B 00 FA FF 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 7F 66 0E 04 6A 1E 00 00 00 00 09 00 EF FF FA FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 86 66 0F 04 0A 23 00 00 00 00 E2 FF F3 FF 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 7C 66 0D 04 6C 0B 00 00 00 00 0E 00 2A 00 43 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 88 66 10 04 D1 2A 00 00 00 00 F1 FF ED FF EF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
06/03/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 76 66 0A 04 64 00 00 00 00 00 F1 D8 F1 D8 F1 D8 00 00 00 00 00 00
18/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 99 68 12 04 3C 12 00 00 00 00 F6 FF F8 FF 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
18/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 95 68 12 04 66 0B 00 00 00 00 EB FF 09 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
18/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 97 68 12 04 24 0E 00 00 00 00 EE FF F8 FF ED FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
18/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 92 68 11 04 E1 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 0A 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
19/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 9E 68 0E 04 7C 0A 00 00 00 00 ED FF F7 FF EB FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
19/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 9B 68 0B 04 58 00 00 00 00 00 E8 FF 1C 00 E8 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
19/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 A6 68 10 04 86 1C 00 00 00 00 F9 FF ED FF 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 AA 68 0C 04 79 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 10 FF E7 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 BB 68 14 04 3C 00 00 00 00 00 FA FF E7 FF 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 B9 68 14 04 3C 00 00 00 00 00 0D 00 15 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 B7 68 13 04 17 4C 00 00 00 00 F2 FF E6 FF E8 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 AC 68 0E 04 4E 04 00 00 00 00 FE FF F8 FF 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 AE 68 0F 04 DA 08 00 00 00 00 07 00 EF FF F9 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 B0 68 11 04 1A 14 00 00 00 00 F0 FF E4 FF 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20/05/2020   11 02 9E 03 21 00 00 00 B3 68 13 04 0F 3D 00 00 00 00 C7 FF EF FF EB FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: What programming language created this? It may be some form of datetime object that has a known encoding.

Comment: That much is not clear to me, but I will try to find out.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It is created by a programme written in GFA Basic.

Comment: Does GFA Basic have a built-in datetime class?

Comment: Well I found this (as updated in the original post), But still not sure it fits with the pattern, so I might be screwed...

Comment: The documented datetime object is 4 bytes while the first 6 bytes seem to be relevant to date.

Comment: The docs also say this is for "XBIOS system routines." Are you sure those are relevant to your bin?

Comment: Ross, thank you for all your help. I actually managed to find out that the above hex sequences do not actually represent date after all. THe dates were in a far more obscure place which I managed to find in the bin files. So you were correct in the first place. Thanks again for your help Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **easily** discernible pattern. If we convert the hexdump to ASCII, we get a bunch of gibberish.

The temp file has the text above, and these operations strip out the dates and pass it to xxd to reverse the hexdump.

```sh
$ cat temp | cut -c12- | tr -d " " | xxd -r -p
p?1??<
???!xf??R?3???v???}Rv???R?(
???!?f????!zff? 
             ?  
                ??
?!fj    ?????!?f
l?????!|f
 *C?!?f?*???????!vf
d???????!?h<????
?!?hf
     ?? 
?!?h$???????!?h?
?!?h|
???????!?h
          X?????!?h?????
                        ?!?h
                            y
?!?hL???????!?hN????
?!?h?????!?h?????!?h=??????
```

If these bytes signify a date, there is a special encoding that you may need to determine based on the programming language it was written it. Or it could be a custom encoding unique to the program in which case it will be more difficult to decipher.